# WCF COM+ component

Tags: wcf, service, components, com+

I have a C# WCF client that is wrapped for COM+ Enterprise Services.  I install the component on the target machine and use regsvcs to put it into Component services.

My question is, where will it look for it's configuration file, as it is running under the dllhost process rather than a regular exe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, a Server COM+ application will look for configuration files in the %windir%\system32 directory.

If you wish to change this location (*which you should!*), you will need to set the Application Root Directory which is in the COM+ Application configuration on the application Activation tab in Component Services.  There you can point to your application specific configuration location.  You will then need to deploy your configuration file and an application manifest to the application root directory.

The full details are at [Using Per-Application Configuration Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms685134%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the post.  I have created the two files required, mine are named MasterCOMInterface.dll.manifest and MasterCOMInterface.dll.config.  I have put these in the same folder as the installed DLL and the System32 folder.  All I seem to get is an error message saying 'Application folder configuration file: C:\WINDOWS\System32\'

I don't suppose anybody had a similar problem?

Comment: It's Ok, I discovered the files actually need to be named 'application.manifest' and 'application.config'.